# How to get from $x^2 + y^2 = e^2(d + x)^2$ to $(\frac{(1-e^2)^2}{e^2d^2})(x-\frac{e^2d}{1-e^2})^2+(\frac{(1-e^2)}{e^2d^2})y^2=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm working through a problem in my pre-calc book and I don't know how to get the equation into the same form as the book.  We start with $x^2 + y^2 = e^2(d + x)^2$ and the book gets to the following form:

$(\frac{(1-e^2)^2}{e^2d^2})(x-\frac{e^2d}{1-e^2})^2+(\frac{(1-e^2)}{e^2d^2})y^2=1$

When I try I get stuck.  Here are my steps:

1.) $x^2 + y^2 = e^2(d + x)^2$

2.) $x^2+y^2 = e^2(d^2 + dx + x^2)$

3.) $x^2+y^2 = e^2d^2 + e^2dx + e^2x^2$

4.) $x^2 - e^2x^2 - e^2dx = e^2d^2 -y^2$ (Grouping like terms)

5.) $(1-e^2)x^2 - e^2dx= e^2d^2 - y^2$

6.) $x^2 - \frac{e^2dx}{(1-e^2)}= \frac{e^2d^2 - y^2}{(1-e^2)}$

7.) $x^2 - \frac{e^2dx}{1-e^2} + (\frac{e^2d}{2(1-e^2)})^2 = \frac{e^2d^2 - y^2}{(1-e^2)} + (\frac{e^2d}{2(1-e^2)})^2$ Completing the square.

8.) $(x^2 - \frac{e^2d}{2(1-e^2)})^2 = \frac{e^2d^2 - y^2}{(1-e^2)} + (\frac{e^2d}{2(1-e^2)})^2$

But from here I don't know where to go.  Any help is Much appreciated.

Comment: The book got it to that form without giving any kind of intermediate steps? If it's a pre-calculus book it has simply got to be more detailed than that.

Comment: Its a free opensource pre-calc book.  You can get a copy at https://www.stitz-zeager.com/szprecalculus07042013.pdf.  The problem is on page 982 and they give a vauge description on how to get it into that form.  Its in the note at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Really nice of you to give me the link. +1

Comment: :)  Its page 982 of the book but when I put the page number into the pdf reader I have to put in page 994.

Comment: Thanks for that, no problem I saw page 982 of the PDF, and the attached section $11.4$. It seems some polar coordinates thing is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be completed

1. given equation
2. you missed a term $dx$ inside the bracket on the RHS
3. $x^2+y^2 = e^2d^2 + 2e^2dx + e^2x^2$
4. $x^2 - e^2x^2 - 2e^2dx = e^2d^2 -y^2$  (same logic with coefficient corrected)
5. $(1-e^2)x^2 - 2e^2dx= e^2d^2 - y^2$
6. $$x^2 - \frac{2e^2dx}{(1-e^2)}= \frac{e^2d^2 - y^2}{(1-e^2)}$$
7. $$x^2 - \frac{2e^2dx}{1-e^2} + (\frac{e^2d}{(1-e^2)})^2 = \frac{e^2d^2 - y^2}{(1-e^2)} + (\frac{e^2d}{(1-e^2)})^2$$ (same logic here)
8. The first term inside the bracket on the LHS should be $x$.  $$(x - \frac{e^2d}{(1-e^2)})^2 = \frac{e^2d^2 - y^2}{(1-e^2)} + (\frac{e^2d}{(1-e^2)})^2$$

Can you continue?

Comment: So you are saying my step to to step 3 is wrong because e^2dx should be 2e^2dx but I don't see where we get the 2 from?

Comment: oh wait, i see it

Comment: let me try and work this out again to see if I can get there.  :)

Comment: I've never learnt that before learning anything in calculus.  I'm sure that you'd be fine even though you don't know this in your future math analysis course.

Comment: Thank you :)  Do you know how to take it from that from your step 8 to the form provided in the book.  I'm still getting stuck.

Comment: You may try 1. moving the $y^2$ term to the LHS.  2. write the RHS into one fraction and post your own attempt in case that you're still stuck

Comment: $(x-\frac{e^2d}{1-e^2})^2+\frac{y^2}{1-e^2}= \frac{e^2d^2}{1-e^2}+(\frac{e^2d}{1-e^2})^2$ but I don't know how to combing the RHS into one fraction.

Comment: $(x-\frac{e^2}{1-e^2})^2+\frac{y^2}{1-e^2}= \frac{(e^2d^2)(1-e^2)+(e^2d)^2}{(1-e^2)^2}$  I'm just not seeing how to get there from here.

Comment: ok, I'm getting closer.  $\frac{(e^2d^2)(1-e^2)+(e^2d)^2}{(1-e^2)^2} = \frac{e^2d^2-e^4d^2+e^4d^2}{1-e^2}= \frac{e^2d^2}{1-e^2}$

Comment: $(x-\frac{e^2d}{1-e^2})^2+\frac{y^2}{1-e^2}=\frac{e^2d^2}{(1-e^2)^2}$

Comment: $(\frac{(1-e^2)^2}{e^2d^2})(x-\frac{e^2d}{1-e^2})^2 + (\frac{(1-e^2)^2}{e^2d^2})(\frac{y^2}{1-e^2})=1$

Comment: $(\frac{(1-e^2)^2}{e^2d^2})(x-\frac{e^2d}{1-e^2})^2 + (\frac{(1-e^2)^2}{e^2d^2})(y)=1$

Comment: Thank you!!! :)

Comment: Glad that you arrived at the your goal